# Can 'Presentation Notes' in Keynote be Locked?

Tags: ipad, keynote

When a speakers private **presentation notes** are produced alongside a **Keynote presentation**, there does not appear to be an opportunity to protect them from editing and/or mistaken deletion. Can they be locked in the same way as the actual presentation frames are locked?

Better still, can the keyboard be temporarily disabled in a particular presentation after it has been finalized? It would stop the distraction of an unwanted pop-up, and it would be useful in preventing unintended typing errors?

Comment: Do you mean to still allow editing of slides?

Comment: No, I mean "locking" the notes in the same way as we lock elements in the presentation itself.